# Laravel auth::attempt return true but auth::check() false why?

Tags: laravel

It prints 0 why? I think it should print 1 when I successfully    authenticate the user. Please help.

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata,true)) 
{
    return Redirect::to('home');
} else
{        
    return Redirect::to('login');
}
```

It redirects me to the home page but when I check

```
if(Auth::check())
{ 
    echo '1'; 
}else
{
    echo '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your routes inside the web middleware route group? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing

Comment: when i put my routes method inside the web middleware it works.Thank you