# Laravel 5.3 can't login with Auth::attempt

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a function

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => 'trannghj', 'password' => 'trannghj2281996'], true, true)) {
    dd(Auth::check());
} else {
    dd('Not login');
}
```

`Auth::attempt` return true but `dd(Auth::check());` return false. I am using Laravel 5.3.

Please help me.

Comment: could you paste how you are creating the user.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `password` column in your `users` table encrypted using bcrypt when you saved them?

Comment: Yes
i use Auth::check() after Auth::attempt return true, and i refresh return false

Comment: A possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633942/laravel-5-2-authcheck-return-true-after-login-but-false-after-redirect Can you try something like this, upon Auth::attempt success redirect to a new page with 'web' middleware and check the result of your Auth::check() there.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815346/laravel-authattempt-return-true-but-authcheck-false-why